# How to build Twilio.dll as a strong-named assembly

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to build a strong-named Twilio.dll to use in our Sharepoint on-premise solution. I tried to build up the solution by downloading the project ->https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp. But I could not install Twilio using the package manager console as it throws me some errors.

[image]

Then I tried to follow the technique of signing the dll with a strong name. http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/ViewCE64BEF3-51A6-4F1C-90C9-6A76B015C9FB.htm

Even though I was able to sign in to the twilio.dll there was an error when adding the dll to the GAC.

[image]

Comment: As I know you can sign assembly if assembly reference signed assemblies too. You should replace referenced nugets with signed one, then try sign your assembly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971449/vs2017-the-operation-failed-as-details-for-project-could-not-be-loaded

Comment: @HansPassant thank you for the provided link. once I changed the project location and tried to execute the don't restore command, I was able to build the project.